# Есть матрица 7x7. Нужно найти наибольшее число в правом треугольнике матрицы и заполнить этот треугольник наибольшими числами

Tags: c++, c, матрицы

В программе нужно задать матрицу 7х7 и заполнить ее целыми числами. Найти наибольшее значение, которое находится в темно-синей части матрицы (скрин ниже) и заполнить выделенную часть матрицы этим значением.
Вывести на экран исходную матрицу, и матрицу после выполнения алгоритма.

[image: Правый треугольник матрицы]

Comment: Ну начните размышлять и реализовывать мысли, а по ходу дела задавайте конкретные вопросы. Для старта - подумать какие индексы элементов в закрашенной части.

Comment: Это я уже узнал, рисовал в пеинте матрицу и писал индексы, но как реализовать не понимаю

Comment: Покажите в в отредактированном вопросе, как заполняете матрицу. Для второго этапа - какие индексы будут у левой точки закрашенного уголка?

Comment: Чтобы реализовать матрицу вам потребуется двумерный массив. Чтобы найти в двумерном массиве максимальный элемент потребуются циклы. Соответственно вам необходимо почитать про массивы и циклы, чтобы понять как это реализовать средствами языка.

Comment: Уже реализовал это задачу, код скину ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось что-то такое, долго парился. Укажите на ошибки пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <locale.h>

#define N 7

int HowMax(int M[N][N], int max);
void change(int M[N][N], int max);

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int Matrix[N][N];
    int max = 0;

    // Чтобы при каждом запуске генерировались рандомные значения
    srand(time(0));

    printf("\tЛабораторная работа №6\n\n");

    // Заполняем матрицу числами от 1 до 9 и выводим её в консоль
    printf("Изначальная матрица: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            Matrix[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 9;
            printf("%2.d", Matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    // Узнаем максимальное значение в правом треугольнике
    max = HowMax(Matrix, max);

    printf("Максимальное значение в правом треугольнике: %d\n\n", max);

    // Заполняем правый треугольних максимальными значениями
    change(Matrix, max);

    // Выводим матрицу после изменений
    printf("Матрица после выполнения алгоритма: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            printf("%2.d", Matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int HowMax(int M[N][N], int max)
{
    for (int i = 6; i >= 3; i--) {
        for (int j = 6; j >= i; j--)
        {
            if (M[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = M[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 6; j >= 6 - i; j--) {
            if (M[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = M[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}

void change(int M[N][N], int max)
{
    for (int i = 6; i >= 3; i--) {
        for (int j = 6; j >= i; j--)
        {
            M[i][j] = max;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 6; j >= 6 - i; j--)
        {
            M[i][j] = max;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: Да нормально. Второй аргумент `HowMax` не нужен, внутри можно начальное значение задать.  В принципе, обход треугольника можно сделать одним циклом `for (int j = 3; j < 7; j++) {  for (int i = 6 - j); i<= j; i++)`

Comment: Нормально. оно работает и это главное. Из недочетов, размер матрицы определяется `#define N 7`, а дальше в циклах используются просто цифры `for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)`, так что если кто-то поменяет N, то ваша программа перестанет работать. Более правильным было бы использовать N во всех циклах

Comment: @goldstar_labs Спасибо, в следующий раз учту